# XFCE - How to change padding between the menu items?

Tags: xfce

I've been using Ambiance theme from a long time, and now I've found this theme namely Adapta I really like, the only problem is the padding or spacing between menu items is just too much. Is there any way to change it?

I'm attaching two ScreeenShot images here, first of my Ambiance theme and second from the Adapta theme. See the difference between them:

Image 1 from Ambiance:
[image: Image 1 from Ambiance]

Image 2 from Adwaita:
[image: Image 2 from Adwaita]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download and read about improved Adwaita theme here : 
http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/adwaita-improved-reduced-padding-for.html